# ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey return null

Tags: docusignapi

I have a problem with SDK Docusign.

```
string sprivateKey = File.ReadAllText(privateKey);
OAuth.OAuthToken tokenInfo = apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey(integratorKey, userId, oauthBasePath, sprivateKey, expiresInHours);
```

`TokenInfo` is not null but all properties are null. 
I don't understand.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: No errors occured, that's weird...no exception.

Comment: i've found the problem, i didn't accept authorization Oauth2 by web portal to user my integration key. it's resolved but i don't understand why it's not occured an exception. perharps a missed feature...

Comment: An exception should have been raised. Do you have any catch blocks? IDE logs?

Comment: i haven't seen IDE logs but perhaps i don't know where to search exactly theses logs and i'm sure that no exception raised even then i had a catch block.

Comment: Which SDK are you using?

Comment: the latest : 2.2.0

Comment: I suggest that you contact DocuSign support